# Arcpy Mosaicing Rasters - Output seems to be wrong

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, mosaic

I am using the ArcPy package for Python 2.7 (with ArcMap 10.1). I tried to write a script that is mosaicing all rasters in my directory, where they overlap it should calculate the mean for the rasters.

This is my script:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/RSIV/Masterarbeit/GRD/Norway/Neu/SentinelSat"

# Import all raster with .TIF in the environment.
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")
arcpy.Mosaic_management (rasters[1:],rasters[0] , "MEAN","FIRST","0", "0", "", "0", "")
```

It works fine, at least its producing the result and overwriting the first raster, but the values are simply wrong for some parts of the image.
The image below shows the identify-tool from ArcMap 10.1, as you can see there is no data in 2 of 3 bands, but the Mean is a little bit of the expected value.

[image]

Can you tell me where I have to update my script/what is going on with the data?

Answer (score 2):

There is likely some amount of resampling going on, which makes your identify example an inappropriate test.

You could try resampling the rasters as a preprocessing step, using one common raster to snap the others to. Then you can use identify to check the mean against the input (pre-snapped) rasters.